# How can I transform HTTP to CoAP by JCoAP?

Tags: http, coap

I use the project [JCoAP](http://code.google.com/p/jcoap/) to do HTTP/CoAP transform.
but I don't know how to use it.
I have a HTTP client and a CoAP server,I need the Proxy to transform HTTP to CoAP,
it's seem that "JCoAP" project have achieve it.But I have no idea the detail 
to use "jCoAP",
Does anyone have any experience?

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally came across this question searching for something similar and as it is not answered and I managed to find something like an answer, here it is:

You can use [californium](https://github.com/eclipse/californium) for this and more specifically its `ProxyHttpServer`. [Here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=californium.core-master/cf-proxy/src/main/java/org/eclipse/californium/examples/ExampleCrossProxy.java) is an example how to do this, but basically you need a `ProxyHttpServer`, `CoapServer` and `ProxyHttpClientResource` and a little bit of *wiring*.